# Jsp page doesn't updated after forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following problem. First of all, I'm send request from jsp to servlet, then I'm doing some operation, and put some data to request, and forward to the same page for rendering new data. But after forwarding, my jsp page doesn't update. Can anyone say me, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Viewer</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"      rel="stylesheet">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFolderRequest(fileName) {
        $.post( "ftp?fileName="+fileName, function( data ) {
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-9  list-group" style="float: none; margin: 20px auto;">
<div class="list-group-item active" style="background-color: darkcyan;">
 Ftp server: /
</div>

<c:forEach items="${requestScope.files}" var="fileEntity">
<p class="list-group-item" onclick="showFolderRequest('${fileEntity.name}')">
            ${fileEntity.name}
        </p>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/ftp")
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        FileManager fileManager = FileManager.getInstance();
        String requestedFileName = req.getParameter("fileName");
        req.setAttribute("files", fileManager.getAllFilesByPath(requestedFileName));
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried in two browsers or only in IE?

Comment: Looks like `fileManager.getAllFilesByPath(requestedFileName)` returns an empty array, list or collection.

Comment: If fileManager.getAllFilesByPath(requestedFileName) return empty list, then I would have seen page with nothing data, but I'm seeing the old page with old data

Comment: Then it's the fault of your browser. Clear any history and try again. Also, try it in several browsers, and keep in mind IE is the worst scenario **always**.

Comment: I'm trying to do in three browsers - IE, firefox and chrome, but everything I have the same behavior. My page page updated, when I was click refresh buttton in browser, but I want that my page update after invoke getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

Comment: After the servlet gets executed, what's the URL in your browser?

Comment: After the servlet gets executed, I have old url in my browser, http://localhost:8080/ftp

Comment: Looks like you're not even hitting the Servlet. Please post the relevant code of your JSP including the `<form>` where you fire the request to the servlet.

Comment: Here is my jsp https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4ch7yxen0vf1pe/view.jsp

Comment: Please select the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22518154/edit) option belo the question content and add the relevant code there. If you have problems formatting the code, just leave it as is, I can format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're firing an ajax request. When handling ajax requests, you need to be aware of some things:

- You **cannot** forward not redirect from your servlet. This is an asynchronous request from the browser and it won't get any content from a forwarding or redirection from the server.
- Expression Language (those things inside `${}`) and JSP tags like JSTL run on server side when processing the JSP and rendering the HTML. Any ajax request **wont** update any EL nor any JSP tag content since this code it is not run on server. So, any new attribute you set here won't matter until you fire a non-ajax request.
- The only way you can get any data from the server is by writing a response that contains the desired data. Usually, you would write a JSON response, but you can even write an XML or a plain text response, it will depend on your design. Then, in the browser side (Javascript), you handle the data from the response and display some text, update values in your current HTML, and on.

From this case, you can write a list of the desired files into a JSON string and write that string in the server response, then manage it accordingly in client side. This is just a bare example of how to achieve it using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to convert Java code into JSON string.

In servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FileManager fileManager = FileManager.getInstance();
    String requestedFileName = req.getParameter("fileName");
    //not really sure what retrieves, I'm assuming it is a Lis<FileEntity>
    //edit this accordingly to your case
    List<FileEntity> files = fileManager.getAllFilesByPath(requestedFileName);
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(files);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFolderRequest(fileName) {
        $.post( "ftp?fileName="+fileName, function( data ) {
            //logs the whole JSON string response into browser console
            //supported in Chrome and Firefox+Firebug
            console.log(data);
            //parsing the JSON response
            var files = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
            //since it is an array, you need to traverse the values
            for (var fileEntity in files) {
                //just logging the files names
                console.log(fileEntity.name);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```